# Symfony 4.1: none of the App classes can be autoloaded in Unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony4

**Problem description**

I have a symfony app. I have created some custom classes that I successfully use in Controller, that is, **those classes are successfully autoloaded when used in a controller**. Nonetheless when I try to test them, they just fail to get autoloaded.

**What I've checked**

- Triple-checked that path and namespace correspond to each other
- Checked my namespace for tests defined in `composer.json`
- Included `./vendor/autoload.php` in test itself -- still no luck. Included manually with `require_once` -- it worked. Since autoloading works fine in "development" mode, that is when it runs not within unit tests, I guess the problem is somewhere in test settings: what to autoload and how.

**My environment**

Here are my `autoload` sections in `composer.json`:

> ```
> "autoload": {
>     "psr-4": {
>         "App\\": "src/"
>     }
> },
>
> "autoload-dev": {
>     "psr-4": {
>         "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
>     }
> },
> ```

Here is my project structure:

[image: My project structure]

Here is the `OrdersTest.php`:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Controller\ViewOrders;

use App\Controller\ViewOrders\Orders;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class OrdersTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testNoneOfTheOrdersCanBeAccepted()
    {
        new Orders();
    }
}
```

Here is the `Order`'s namespace:

```
namespace App\Controller\ViewOrders;
```

Here is my `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.5/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

**How to reproduce**

```
$ ./bin/phpunit // in project root
```

Here is the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 35 ms, Memory: 6.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) App\Tests\Controller\ViewOrders\OrdersTest::testNoneOfTheOrdersCanBeAccepted
Error: Class 'App\Controller\ViewOrders\Orders' not found

/home/vadim/projects/webApp/tests/Controller/ViewOrders/OrdersTest.php:14
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does adding <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" /><env name="APP_ENV" value="test" /> in the <php> section of your phpunit.xml.dist have any effect?

Comment: @Chris still no luck

Comment: Well, then the only difference to my Testproject is the directory under <filter><whitelist>. I got "./src/" instead of your "src".

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload --optimize` after your changes? As this may be related to file permissions ... Did you try simply removing the `vendor` folder and re-running `composer install --optimize`  again?

Comment: Could you check the `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` file to verify that your entry for `App` is there? Also I would recommend that you'd check the `composer.json` and both class files with a hex editor to make sure there are no non-printable characters in any of the namespaces.